# Add non-relational attribute to EF Entity (Join Operation)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, jqgrid

I've a model as described below:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; } //from City
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; } //from State
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; } //from Country
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

*I wants to query the Student Entity and needs to include the Country (Only Country) to the student Model.
The Database structure is like as above, I cannot change the DB Table Structure.*

**But I can able to edit the EF Entities above. Ultimately I need the Student info with country as a Student Entity, So that I can draw jqGrid and sort them based on country too.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you can't modify your entity classes to add the corresponding navigation properties, you can try this:

```
var query = from student in context.Students
            join city in context.Cities on student.CityId equals city.Id
            join state in context.States on city.StateId equals state.Id
            join country in context.Countries on state.CountryId equals country.Id
            select new {
                         StudentId=student.Id,
                         Level=student.Level,
                         ...
                         Country=country.Country
                       };
```

Or maybe:

```
           select new {Student=student, Country=country.Country};
```

If your tables are related, I suggest you include the navigation properties to your model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public int CityId { get; set; } //from City

    public virtual City City{get;set;}
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public int StateId { get; set; } //from State

     public virtual City City{get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Student> Students{get;set;}
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public int CountryId { get; set; } //from Country
    public virtual Country Country {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities{get;set;}
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<State> States{get;set;}
}
```

That is not going to affect your current DB schema. This way is more easy to reach to the *country name* using a *student instance* (as @SteveGreene show in his answer):

```
var countryName=student.City.State.Country.Country;
```

Comment: Thanks! The country is nowhere related to the Student table by the way.
Will the result be a Student Model?
I need the result to be a student model, So that I can do sorting easily on the jqGrid thing. 
And I can modify the Student Model but not the table.
(CodeFirst Method)

Comment: it's an anonymous type with all the properties that have `Student` + the country name

Comment: Thanks! I need the type as Student model, Is there any possibility that we can have any virtual attribute for County, So that the model looks as below:
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; } //from City

    public virtual Country { get; set; }
}

Comment: Maybe you could use a [NopMapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped) property to hold the country name but I suggest you save the result of your query in a [DTO](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) object.

Answer (score 1):

You can project that into an anonymous object or viewmodel:

```
var studentWithCountry = context.Student.Where(Id = myVar.Id)
   .Select(s => new { Level = s.Level,
                      Subject = s.Subject,
                      ...
                      Country = s.City.State.Country.Country });
```

Comment: Thanks! I need the result as Student model. I can modify the Student model to adopt the country-relation but not the DB table.
And It's code first EF method, So changes need not to affect the DB

Comment: Right, for this to work you need to add the navigation properties octavioccl suggests. Those shouldn't change the database since you are conforming to the entity + Id foreign key convention. Unless the relationships aren't defined in the DB.